# How do i get rid of Error: bucket is required in node aws3 and multers3

Tags: node.js

I specified the variable from my config.env file but still getting error "bucket is required"

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    // bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    key: function (req, res, cb) {
      cb(null, `user-${req.user.id}-${Date.now()}.jpeg`);
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Attach a debugger and check the value of `process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME`. How do you load your `config.env`?

Comment: I did console.log(s3.config.credentials) and got null, when i hardcode the credentials, it works, but that is not what i want. My other variables not that of s3 from my config.env file appears to be working fine. So its hard for me to figure why the AWS variables are not working.